# How limit height in access report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I try to print a ticket using a thermal printer, but i have a issue. I remove footer and other things, but access use **A4 format** for default.

I want to know how create a report based in the data i will printer. I used Access 2013.

[image: image ticket]

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're asking. Is there a black border extending the full length of the page that you don't want? Is there a separate region showing up below your data? Or is it just that your data only uses the top half of the page and you're bothered that there's whitespace below? Could you attach a picture of your actual printout or a screenshot of a PDF of it?

Comment: I found the option of the printer, then I saw that there were some advanced options, which asked for administrator permission, there I found an option, which specifies that when I saw a specific symbol, in my case a string of asterisks ` ********* `, the printer automatically stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an arduous research, I found a solution that would not only apply to Access, but that it can be used in any instance that is possible.

The solution I found without using a code was to send the printer a warning that when you see a symbol, you can also use a letter or a number, stop, since that would be the end of the page, use The symbol of the asterisk to inform the printer that that the end of the page and that it had to stop.

[Link with the solution](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54341/limitar-el-tama%C3%B1o-de-un-informe-en-access-al-momento-de-imprimir)